# GenerateProjectFile error Referenced directory [...] does not exist

Tags: unreal-4, installer

I am following [this tutorial](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/GitHub_Setup) to install Unreal Engine 4.22 from GitHub on Windows. I forked the project and cloned it on my computer. I've executed `Setup.bat` and everything went fine, but when I execute `GenerateProjectFiles.bat` I get all these errors:

```
PS D:\software\UnrealEngine> .\GenerateProjectFiles.bat
Setting up Unreal Engine 4 project files...
Binding IntelliSense data...
D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\IntelTBB\IntelTBB.Build.cs: warning: Referenced directory 'D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\IntelTBB\IntelTBB-4.4u3\Include' does not exist.
D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\DirectShow\DirectShow.Build.cs: warning: Referenced directory 'D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\DirectShow\DirectShow-1.0.0\Lib\Win64\vs2015' does not exist.
D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Ogg\UEOgg.Build.cs: warning: Referenced directory 'D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Ogg\libogg-1.2.2\lib\Win64\VS2015' does not exist.
D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Vorbis\Vorbis.Build.cs: warning: Referenced directory 'D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Vorbis\libvorbis-1.3.2\Lib\win64\VS2015' does not exist.
D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Vorbis\VorbisFile.Build.cs: warning: Referenced directory 'D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Vorbis\libvorbis-1.3.2\Lib\win64\VS2015' does not exist.
D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\OpenSSL\OpenSSL.Build.cs: warning: Referenced directory 'D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\OpenSSL\1.1.1\include\Win64\VS2015' does not exist.
D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\OpenSSL\OpenSSL.Build.cs: warning: Referenced directory 'D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\OpenSSL\1.1.1\lib\Win64\VS2015\Release' does not exist.
D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Kiss_FFT\Kiss_FFT.Build.cs: warning: Referenced directory 'D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Kiss_FFT\kiss_fft129\lib\x64\VS2015\Release' does not exist.
D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\VHACD\VHACD.Build.cs: warning: Referenced directory 'D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\VHACD\lib\Win64\VS2015' does not exist.
D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Plugins\Experimental\ProxyLODPlugin\Source\ThirdParty\OpenVDB.Build.cs: warning: Referenced directory 'D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\IntelTBB\IntelTBB-4.4u3\include' does not exist.
D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Qualcomm\TextureConverter\QualcommTextureConverter.build.cs: warning: Referenced directory 'D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Qualcomm\TextureConverter\Lib\vs2015\x64' does not exist.
Binding IntelliSense data... 0%ImportError: No module named site
Python SDK not found
D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Plugins\Runtime\LeapMotion\Source\LeapMotion\LeapMotion.Build.cs: warning: Referenced directory 'D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\ThirdParty\Leap\Include' does not exist.
D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Plugins\Runtime\nDisplay\Source\DisplayCluster\DisplayCluster.Build.cs: warning: Referenced directory 'D:\software\UnrealEngine\Engine\Plugins\Runtime\nDisplay\ThirdParty\VRPN\Include' does not exist.
Binding IntelliSense data... 100%
Writing project files... 100%
PS D:\software\UnrealEngine>
```

At the end of this command it creates a UE4.sln (but no UE4.v12.suo file) but when I try to compile the project on Visual Studio 2019 I get plenty of errors that are quite reminiscent of the ones above, so I assume the problem comes from the generation of the project files.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Seems like it wants to be compiled with vs2015

Answer (score 1):

Python3 needs to be installed and add `python.exe` to Environment Variables of OS.